# Как запустить index.php на локальном сервере xampp?

Tags: php

Разрабатываю свой движок на php по этому уроку - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUgtft0hTps

Я создал тир файла index.php (единая точка входа), .htaccess и setting.php (пока пустой)

Файл index.php:

```
<?php
   include_once 'setting.php';



   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){
     $Page = 'index';
     $Module = 'index';
   } else {
     $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
     $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
     $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
     $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);


   if (!empty($Module)) {
      $Param = array();

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
          $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
      }
    }
  }


 if ($Page == "index" and $Module == "index") echo "Главная страница";
 else if ($Page == "photo") echo "Фотогалерея";
?>
```

Файл .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ошибки нет. Но и не выводится ничего. Этот блок не работает как надо. Ввожу следующее: http://localhost/cosmologia/index - должен вывести "Главная страница", но не выводит.

```
if ($Page == "index" and $Module == "index") echo "Главная страница";
else if ($Page == "photo") echo "Фотогалерея";
?>
```

Comment: Проверьте апачи лог. error.log/access.log

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить логи?

Comment: `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: Догадка у вас или `mod_rewrite` не активирован или Пути неправильные.

Comment: если ты разрабатываешь свой движок то уже не лучше ли перейти на норм сервер ? установить lamp вместо урезанного xamp

Comment: Разве от этого будут какие-то изменения? Почему-то мне кажется, что ошибка все равно останется, не смотря на изменение сервера

Comment: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` - напутаны пути,  что бы проверить `Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` ;). `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters` - синтаксическая ошибка.  http://www.htaccesscheck.com/index.html Для проверки `.htaccess` файла

Comment: Очень важная ошибка! `Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO ...` С версии 7 `mysql_*` удалён полностью! Если учесть, что сейчас развивается/поддерживается только ветка 5.6 то скоро ваше приложение не будет работать на актуальной ветке ПХП.

Comment: `array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given`  - Похоже база вернула ошибку.

Comment: `http://localhost/index/index` -> `Главная страница` ;)

Comment: Пролистал бегло эти уроки, советую отказаться от них, ибо эти уроки ни к чему ДЕЛЬНОМУ не приведут, куча уязвимостей, кривая архитектура да и сама концепция неправильная. Мой совет ищите другие от греха подальше.

Answer (score 1):

У вас огромное количество ошибок. Мой совет,  вернуться к началу. Ни каких БД, маршрутизации и тд...

**.htaccess**

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Вам эти две строки не нужны. Они при перенаправлении передают заголовки авторизации. 
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    #RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die();
```

Данный скрипт будет возвращать путь после имени сервера.
`http://localhost/cosmologia/index.php` -> `/cosmologia/index.php`
`http://localhost/ololo` -> `/ololo`

Проверьте что все работает.
Потом добавляйте маршрутизацию и БД.

Comment: Никаких ошибок не выдает, но не работает этот блок кода

if ($Page == 'index' and $Module == 'index') echo 'Главная страница';
else if ($Page == 'photo') echo 'Фотогалерея';
else if ($Page == 'comment') echo 'Комментарии';
else if ($Page == 'register') echo 'Регистрация';

Comment: @user207012 Вы пробовали удалить весь код, и оставить только то, что я показал в ответе?

Comment: @user207012 Смотрите мой коментарий под вашим вопросом.